# Getting error message from range.formula function

Tags: excel, vba, random, range, simulation

I have tried to run this sub for generating a random sample, but when I try to fix the formula I get only an error message in the cells " Name", in state of gettings the values.
Can someone help?

This is the code, thanks:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Simulation()

    Dim iSize As Integer, pMean As Double, pSD As Double, iBins As String

    iBins = 15
    iSize = InputBox("New sheet: The size of your sample:", , 100)
    pMean = InputBox("New sheet: The mean of yoursample:", , 10)
    pSD = InputBox("New sheet: The SD of your sample:", , 0.2)

    Set oWS = Worksheets.Add(, ActiveSheet)

    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(iSize, 1)).Formula = "=Application.WorksheetFunction.NormInv(Rnd(), " & pMean & " , " & pSD & ")"
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(iSize, 1)).Formula = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(iSize, 1)).Value

    Range("E1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Columns(1))
end sub
```

Comment: `Range.Formula` needs a formula like you would input in Excel cells, take out the `.Formula` from your ranges and it will work allright.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```vb
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(iSize, 1)).Formula = "=NormInv(Rand(), " & pMean & " , " & pSD & ")"
```

Comment: @said `Rnd` is a VBA function. Try Excel's `RAND` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you type `=Application.WorksheetFunction.NormInv(Rnd(), 10, 0.2)` in a worksheet cell, you'll get the exact same `#NAME?` error, because Excel doesn't know about any `Application.WorksheetFunction.NormInv` function.

Excel isn't VBA, VBA isn't Excel - VBA is *hosted* in Excel, and your VBA project *references* Excel's type library, which defines things like `Application`, `Range`, and `WorksheetFunction.NormInv`.

When writing to `Range.Formula`, you want that value to be exactly what you would type in Excel's formula bar.

Also you'll want to properly qualify these `Range` and `Cells` calls:

```
With oWS
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(iSize, 1)).Formula = "..."
End With
```

Where `"..."` looks exactly like it does in [PaichengWu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57996596/1188513), except you want to use Excel's `RAND` function instead of VBA's `Rnd` function.